# Error while querying tables using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to query a table called `student` in MySQL. This is the structure:

[image: mysql_error]

Here is the java code which I use to query:

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;

import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class QueryStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();
        
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            List<Student> list = session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList();
            
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println(list);
        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the error message:

```
May 25, 2022 6:40:05 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=hbstudent}
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 25, 2022 6:40:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
May 25, 2022 6:40:07 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
May 25, 2022 6:40:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
May 25, 2022 6:40:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections close
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections upon shutting down pool jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
May 25, 2022 6:40:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl validateConnectionsReturned
ERROR: Connection leak detected: there are 1 unclosed connections!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.QueryStudentDemo.main(QueryStudentDemo.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 14 more
```

Here is the image of the `referenced libraries`:

[image: ref_lib]

Insertion into table is working correctly. Only querying isn't.

What is the error here?

Please comment if extra information is needed.

**UPDATE**:

It worked when I added `antlr` to my class path

Comment: Can you share libraries list which you are using / pom.xml?

Comment: @Kiran, I am not using maven. So I have put a image of the `referenced libraries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per exception stack trace, it looks like `antlr/RecognitionException` class file is missing. Add below dependency and try. This should solve your issue.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```